# Como usar except no mysql

Tags: php, mysql, aplicação-web

Preciso fazer um select em uma tabela de oferta e em seguida usar um except para excluir o resultado do outro select

Exemplo:

> A = {10,11,12} 
>   B = {11,12} 
>   (A except B) = {10}

estou falando de except pq pelo que eu tinha pesquisado, da certo o código abaixo no sql server mas eu queria um código parecido em mysql ou então se possível pode ser algo em php

```
SELECT ofe.ofeCodigo, ofe.ofeTitulo FROM tbloferta ofe, tblcategoriaoferta cof WHERE ofe.cofCodigo = cof.cofCodigo AND ofe.ofeStatus = 'Aberto' AND cof.cofDescricao = 'Compra'
EXCEPT
SELECT ofe.ofeCodigo, ofe.ofeTitulo FROM tbloferta ofe, tblofertanegociacao ofeneg, tblcategoriaoferta cof WHERE ofe.ofeCodigo = ofeneg.ofeCodigo AND ofe.cofCodigo = cof.cofCodigo AND ofeneg.negCodigo = 40 AND cof.cofDescricao = 'Compra'
```

Comment: Creio que o MySQL não implementa as operações de combinação de queries EXCEPT e INTERSECT, apenas a UNION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acredito que o `EXCEPT` não funciona no **MySql**, mas você pode tentar usar o `NOT IN`. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT 
    ofe.ofeCodigo, 
    ofe.ofeTitulo 
    FROM 
        tbloferta ofe, 
        tblcategoriaoferta cof 
    WHERE 
        ofe.cofCodigo = cof.cofCodigo AND 
        ofe.ofeStatus = 'Aberto' AND 
        cof.cofDescricao = 'Compra' AND
        ofe.ofeCodigo NOT IN (
            SELECT ofe.ofeCodigo 
            FROM 
                tbloferta ofe, 
                tblofertanegociacao ofeneg, 
                tblcategoriaoferta cof 
            WHERE 
                ofe.ofeCodigo = ofeneg.ofeCodigo AND 
                ofe.cofCodigo = cof.cofCodigo AND 
                ofeneg.negCodigo = 40 AND 
                cof.cofDescricao = 'Compra'
        )
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, isso mesmo que eu queria, uma alternativa ao EXCEPT do sql server no mysql, funcionou